# ConfigurationManager Class

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, configurationmanager

How do you use the COnfigurationManager class to read and write to the settings file?

Comment: Have you googled before coming here?

Comment: Yes, I certainly have. I got a few links, which I tried out. I am also referencing a book called "Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform" by Andrew Troelson. I am trying out examples from that book. The book says, the app.exe.config gets overwritten everytime, I compile. I am not experiencing this in VS 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could try and give you the breakdown here but really the following links, all written by Jon Rista, are the best resources I have found regarding the System.Configuration namespace.

[Unravelling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)

[Decoding the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)

[Cracking the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links. The final link contained a reference to the machine.config file. This file contains my "rogue" string mentioned in my comment to SpaceCracker below. I believe I have figured out the configuration management system for .NEt executables.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that might catch you out is that to access the ConfigurationManager class you have to manually add a reference to System.Configuration. The System.Configuration namespace is split across multiple assemblies - you only get part of it by default.

Space Cracker posted some good links, but there is also a way to write strongly typed configuration sections, which I blogged about a few years ago - [Configuring a .NET 2.0 Application Using the ConfigurationSection class](http://alexhumphrey.me.uk/net/configuring-a-net-2-0-application-using-the-configurationsection-class/). I've literally never seen anyone else use strongly typed ConfigurationSections, but once you get used to them they're quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

check the following
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SystemConfiguration.aspx

Comment: One thing I have been experiencing is that a rogue string comes up when I do a loop through the connectionstrings section I have no idea, how this rogue string is being populated. For example, my connectionStrings section has got
a> prod
b> dev
c> uat
strings in it.

When I loop through connectionStrings section, using this code.
     foreach (ConnectionStringSettings key in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ConKey: {0}, Value:{1}", key.Name, key.ConnectionString.ToString());

                }
           

I get 4 strings.